# Fat-Free startup

Tags: apache, fat-free-framework

I am looking at the FatFree framework but I am falling at the very first hurdle.

I am running Apache on Windows10, php5.6

I installed the fat-free distribution in my 'vendor' directory which is immediately below my server root directory.  Also beneath the root directory I created a new project directory 'NewProject' and in it I put the following index.php

```
<?php
define ('F3LIB','../vendor/FatFree/lib');
$f3 = require (F3LIB.'/base.php');
$f3->route('GET /',
    function() {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }
);
$f3->run();
```

When I then type `/localhost/NewProject` in my browser I just get: HTTP 404 (GET /index.php)

I have tried things like `GET /NewProject` but no difference to the result. Research suggests I may need a variant `.htaccess` file - I have tried one or two ideas but without success. If necessary which directory would I need to put it in?

I have tried this .htaccess file:

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require you to specify the `RewriteBase` directive
# In such cases, it should be the path (relative to the document root)
# containing this .htaccess file
#
RewriteBase NewProject

RewriteRule ^(tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

I am a complete newbie as far as the content of .htaccess files goes, I have never so far needed one in my project.  I extracted the text from an answer posted in relation to a similar question.

Comment: You're using composer, right?

Comment: From what I see, your issue is not PHP related. Your issue is clearly Apache related. For some reason, you're not even serving your `index.php`.

Comment: If I were you, I'd drop stand-alone Apache and I'd look into using a VM (either pure VirtualBox or Vagrant through VirtualBox) or using Docker.

Comment: Docker is not the answer to everything. It's the new `jQuery` of answers on Stack. This question is missing a docroot. If I recall, F3 requires a specific docroot to be set. Set up a proper vhost entry and follow its install directions.

Comment: The issue is with .htaccess, can you post yours?

Comment: To answer above comments:

Comment: To answer above comments: a) Although I did extract it directly from the distribution, I have also subsequently run Composer and it said it, and all dependencies, were correct. b) My index.php IS being served. This is easily demonstrated by commenting out the third line after which, logically enough, it complains about undefined variable f3. c) I am afraid I do not understand the VM/Docker references. d) I have posted an update in including a .htaccess file that I tried. I suspect this may be the key to getting things working.

Comment: The `RewriteBase` directive looks wrong. Try removing it or setting it to `/NewProject/`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was unsure of the syntax, but I had already tried both those options with no effect.

Comment: Then try `$f3->ONERROR=function($f3){echo $f3->URI;};` just before `$f3->run()`. Then call `http://localhost/NewProject/` and we should know if the framework receives the correct URI or not.

Comment: It now returns /NewProject/

Comment: Oops - My last comment was indeed correct - but in the meantime I had decided to reinstall fatfree starting from the NewProject directory, so it is now in a vendor directory below the project directory and guess what - it now works!  I shall carry on for now but at some stage, if I decide to use it again on future projects I would rather it were in a subdirectory a level up. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In case it should help someone else in the future I can now confirm that I have found the real cause of my problem. Following the above comments I found that I had started getting the basic "hello world" working but attempts to reach other routes "/about" etc. were still failing.

After further research I discovered that, as well as activating the mod_dir module in the Appache http.conf you must also make sure that you allow mods by setting "AllowOverride All" in the Directory section for the root DocumentRoot directory, otherwise the .htaccess file has no effect.  This is what I had failed to do and all was well afterwards.  In fact, after doing that, I don't seem to require the RewriteBase line.

Also worth note is that the built in php5 server seems work a treat without the need for special settings, just start it with "php -S localhost:PORT -t YourDocumentRootPath"